# Are there cultures in which walking in the nude in public is not frowned upon?

Tags: where-on-earth, local-customs, culture, nudism

Although some cultures are less prudent then others I have the impression that walking in the nude in public is frowned upon world wide. Is this a correct assumption?

I know that for example going to the sauna in some countries requires you to go full monty, whereas in others it is considered offensive. So answers mentioning nude beaches, saunas and other designated areas are invalid. I am simply wondering is you can walk on the street naked without getting into trouble.

Comment: Also: Are there cultures without “streets”?

Comment: @Annoyed  Nomadic culture might have no street. Depending on the camp design.

Comment: @Madlozoz Obviously. It was meant as a gentle poke on the question.

Comment: Don't worry, mine was just a gentle poke at your comment. 
But as I can't help having the last word, Sea gypsies definitely have no street

Comment: You have obviously never seen a National Geographic magazine.

Comment: I think in Brasil it's actually pretty common.

Comment: Note that the definition of "naked" varies from culture, and may or may not involve hiding the genitalia and mammaries. "There are cultures where being dressed involves as little as a piece of string around the waist, but it is indecent to go out without the string."

I'll also point out that there is no US federal law against nudity per se (which is why nude beaches are generally on federal land rather than state land).

Comment: What do you mean with "getting into trouble"? If you mean legal trouble, there are many countries, in which public nudity per se is not illegal. That alone does of course not mean that noone will frown upon someone without clothes. And how do you define a "nude beach"? An area, on which nudity is officially allowed or an area, on which nudity is acceptable? If you follow the last definition, your question does not make sense. If you follow the first question, there are also many countries, in which nudity is acceptable and tolerated on "regular" beaches as well.

Comment: "Less prudent"? Do you mean "Less prudish"?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo and other countries where it's technically legal but de-facto illegal because of special clauses in the law giving LEOs and courts great power to arrest and fine/imprison. E.g. Dutch law does not outlaw public nudity except "in view of a public roadway and where inappropriate" without defining "in view", "public roadway" or "inappropriate", having led to arrests of people bathing naked on a boat several miles from a shipping lane where they could only be observed by strong binoculars from a police boat or helicopter.

Comment: In Saudi Arabia, Iran and Afghanistan it is a common practice. LOL!

Answer (score 8):

Yep, a good friend of mine lives in Ghana. He says that, when out and about on particularly hot days, he meets Ghanaians who have neglected to put on clothes before leaving the house.

Comment: bada-tssh. Where in Ghana does he live? As this is certainly not typical for city life in Ghana, where going nude would very much be frowned upon.

Comment: South of lake volta. I'm not sure how large his town is but I figure that's beside the point.

Comment: It is not besides the point if it's taken as representative for the whole country.

Comment: @MastaBaba to be technical, it is besides the point, as the question was if cultures exist where nudity is not frowned upon.  The answer is yes.  As an example, apparently in some areas of Ghana - from anecdotal evidence from a friend - it is not unusual.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your exact question is "No"

"Street" imply an urban environment and, if you are above 10 year old, no such place would accept public nudity.

That said, you can find some remote tribes in Papua. I heard also about Mentawai Island(south west Sumatra). Once again, it would be deep in the forest. Not in the (relatively) cosmopolitan harbor.

In both case, I am pretty sure they would frown at a white guy walking naked in their village.

http://www.papuatrekking.com/First_Contact_expedition.html

Comment: You can also find some tribes in the Brazilian amazon that wear nothing.

Comment: @Madladoz Perhaps you're thinking of the Mentawai? I don't think they go naked though, and the vast majority have now been herded into settlements and have abandoned their traditional ways. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentawai_people

Comment: @lambshaanxy I was indeed talking about a documentary about Mentawai. I edited the post. I haven't been there (I lived north of sumatra where people frown on short pants). I can just tell that the documentary shot in the 2000's showed people walking around naked.